# File has date column names

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am attempting to import a file that has date's as column names.

For example:

- Order Number
- Total
- jan2012
- Feb2012

I would like to change this when I import it in as:

- Order Number
- Total
- Date

So, the table would look like:

```
OrderNumber    Total       Date 
1                5         Jan2012 
1                6         Feb2012 
2                3         Jan 2012 
2                4         Feb2012
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What? Please give an example of a few lines of input and the output you want.

Comment: Did you consider importing as is and then using unpivot to create the format that you want?

Comment: @GordonLinoff has a very good suggestion. I would certainly start there.

Answer (score 0):

that is called a PIVOT transformation and there is a task specific to do that.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is a link to a SQL example (if you want to understand how it works)

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140308.aspx) is the SSIS PIVOT transformation

and example [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/eric_johnson/archive/2010/10/20/the-ssis-pivot-transformation.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This type of transformation is an `UNPIVOT`:

```
select OrderNumber, Total, Date
from yourtable
unpivot
(
    date
    for col in (jan2012, Feb2012)
) unpiv
```

Or you can use `UNION ALL`:

```
select ordernumber, total, jan2012 as date
from yourtable
union all
select ordernumber, total, feb2012 as date
from yourtable
```